# is it possible to use x in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, switch-statement, try-catch

ok, the idea is to put an x as the arrays number, so I can count up and print a series of things, and also input the thing at the same time.

The goal is to count up with x in the array [] and save a defined variable and promptly print it.

I wouldn't consider myself good programmer, just getting into it. 
Can anyone help me with this problem because the below code doesn't work, it might just be a syntax error for all I know!

```js
try {
  var m;
  var b[5];
  for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    switch (b[x]) {
      case 0:
        b[x] = "bock ";
      case 1:
        b[x] = "look ";
        break;
      case 2:
        b[x] = "boke ";
        break;
      case 3:
        b[x] = "alle ";
        break;
      case 4:
        b[x] = "pore ";
        break;
      case 5:
        b[x] = "goet ";
        break;
    }
    document.write(b[x]);
  }
}
catch (err) {
  document.write("an error has occurred.<br>" + err);
}
```

Comment: `switch(x) { ` instead of `switch(b[x])`

Comment: No, `var b[5];` is indeed not valid syntax

Comment: `var b[5];` is syntax invalid

Comment: thank you, I should have checked the syntax better, I'll be certain to learn more about arrays and memorize syntax better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve

```js
var b = [];

try {
    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                b[x] = "bock ";
            case 1:
                b[x] = "look ";
                break;
            case 2:
                b[x] = "boke ";
                break;
            case 3:
                b[x] = "alle ";
                break;
            case 4:
                b[x] = "pore ";
                break;
            case 5:
                b[x] = "goet ";
                break;
        }
        console.log(b[x]);
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log("an error has occurred.<br>" + err);
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I've fixed it accordingly and have updated it and tested it, it works perfectly!

Comment: @MEI Did you try and check the result?

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

1. `var b = []` instead of `var b = [5]`
2. `switch(x) {` instead of `switch(b[x])`

```js
var m;  
  var b = [];
  for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
      switch(x) { 
        case 0: 
          b[0] = "bock "; 
        case 1:
          b[1] = "look ";
          break; 
        case 2: 
          b[2] = "boke ";
          break;
        case 3:
          b[3] = "alle "; 
          break;
        case 4:
          b[4] = "pore ";
          break;
        case 5: 
          b[5] = "goet "; 
        break; 
    }
}

  console.log(b);
```

Comment: This is lovely, this is exactly what i was going for, wonderful!